# Is a C# Constructor thread safe?

Tags: c#, multithreading, constructor

Let's say I have multiple threads and each of them is trying to create objects of the same class.
Will the simultaneous creation of objects of the same type in different threads interfere with each other? 
Do I need to use "lock" within the constructor?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This depends very much on the implementation of the constructor.

If the constructor is only accessing members of that class, and not any external static classes or methods, then yes - it is thread safe.

But if that constructor is accessing non-threadsafe objects that exist outside of the class itself, (such as a global singleton), then it is not threadsafe.

update: The constructor should be careful not to access any static members of the class that are not readonly or const.  (thanks Nathan A and LVBen)

Comment: For the sake of completeness, I'd update that to include *if you are not accessing **any** static members of that class*, not just "**external** static classes or methods".  Accessing internal static members are just as non-thread safe as external static members.

Comment: Static read-only and const members of the class would be OK.  However, you would have to be careful using other static members.

Comment: `const` members would be safe.  `static readonly` members are not necessarily safe.  You would need to ensure the proper memory barriers are in place first.

Comment: Servy, can you explain that, please?

Comment: Nevermind, I did some more research and I think I can answer my own question now.  You can have static readonly members that are not thread safe, thus making constructors that use them also not thread safe.