# Parallel.ForEach variables aren't treated as local

Tags: c#-4.0, parallel-processing

I'm writing a file system searcher that takes directories (typically Windows drives) and filters as input and searches each input directory for files matching the input filters. Sequentially, I implemented it like so (simplified version of relevant code):

```cs
foreach (var dir in Directories) {
    Console.WriteLine("Searching: " + dir);
    var s = new FSSearcher(dir, FileTypes, Keywords, SearchContents);
    s.Search();
}

class FSSearcher {

    [...]
    private static List<string> Filetypes;
    private static List<string> Keywords;
    private static List<string> Results;
    private static bool searchContents;
    private static string SearchDirectory;
    [...]

    public FSSearcher(string d, List<string> f, List<string> k, bool s) {
        SearchDirectory = d;
        Filetypes = f;
        Keywords = k;
        Results = new List<string>();
        searchContents = s;
    }

    public void Search() {
            if (Directory.Exists(SearchDirectory)) {
                Console.WriteLine("Searching dir: " + SearchDirectory);
                [...]

            }
    }
}
```

This code works correctly and as expected. No results need to be collected at the end of the loop. FSSearcher is an "independent class". Now I want to run this `foreach` loop in parallel (different physical drives, so concurrency should not be throttled by I/O), so I changed the code above to the following (again simplified code):

```
var ConcurrentDirectories = new ConcurrentBag<string>();
ConcurrentDirectories.Add("C:\\");
ConcurrentDirectories.Add("Z:\\");
var options = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = ConcurrentDirectories.Count };
Parallel.ForEach(ConcurrentDirectories, options, (dir) => {
        Console.WriteLine("Searching in parallel: " + dir);
        var s = new FSSearcher(dir, FileTypes, Keywords, SearchContents);
        s.Search();
});
```

I'm assuming variable `s` is local to each iteration. However, this is not the case. The code above gives the following output:

```
Searching in parallel: Z:\
Searching in parallel: C:\
Searching dir: C:\
Searching dir: C:\ <=== this is expected to be Z:\
```

What appears to happen is that `s` is initialized for `Z:\` in one "iteration" and then re-assigned to another instance of FSSearcher for `C:\`. Then `Search()` is called twice for the last assigned object for `C:\`.

I've read through all the related SO posts for an explanation or solution, but cannot seem to find an explanation. How is this happening and how can I prevent it from happening?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The issue here was that I was assigning `static` variables in the constructor of `FSSearch`. Assigning static variables in a constructor [is apparently not thread-safe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23789159/3212927). I changed my code to the following which made this concurrency issue evaporate:

```
class FSSearcher {

    [...]
    private List<string> Filetypes;
    private List<string> Keywords;
    private List<string> Results;
    private bool searchContents;
    private string SearchDirectory;
    [...]

    public FSSearcher(string d, List<string> f, List<string> k, bool s) {
        this.SearchDirectory = d;
        this.Filetypes = f;
        this.Keywords = k;
        this.Results = new List<string>();
        this.searchContents = s;
    }

    public void Search() {
            if (Directory.Exists(SearchDirectory)) {
                Console.WriteLine("Searching dir: " + SearchDirectory);
                [...]

            }
    }
}
```